# jasmine-node doesnt wait for body to be done

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am currently able to pass a test with

```
expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200)
```

but doing this line right underneath

```
expect(body.name).toEqual('erilcompa')
```

gives me a undefined.
**console.log(body) however gives the body**

All of it looks like this:

```
var request = require("request");
var base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api"


 describe("Routes Suite", function(){
     var customerID;
    it("should make a quotation", function(done){

        request.post({url:base_url + '/customer', 
        form: {
          'name': 'erilcompa',
          'vatNr': '22',
        }},
        function(error,response, body){

          expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200)
          expect(body.name).toEqual('erilcompa')
          customerID = body.name

          console.log(response.statusCode)

          done()
        })  
    })
 )}
```

It's probably something obvious but any help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JSON.parse to parse the body, because the type of the body argument is string.

```
var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
expect(bodyObj.name).toEqual('erilcompa');
```

Note that your server must send a well-formed JSON format object

```
{"name":"erilcompa"}
```

Your code should be like this:

var request = require("request");
var base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api"

```
describe("Routes Suite", function(){
    var customerID;
    it("should make a quotation", function(done){

        request.post({url:base_url + '/customer', 
            form: {
                'name': 'erilcompa',
                'vatNr': '22',
            }
        },
        function(error,response, body){
            expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);
            var bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
            expect(bodyObj.name).toEqual('erilcompa');
            customerID = body.name;
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            done();
        })  
    })
)}
```